# Mobile Responsive Design With Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I would Like to get suggestion about my Website on Wordpress about Mobile Responsive design. This is because I have received a warning with Google Webmaster about Widen content issue in Mobile version.

www.reifenschubert.de

Thanks for reading and would be very glad to receive your comments

Comment: you are using bootstrap.css, what else you want, use that and make it mobile compatible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jetpack plugin , it offers a free responsive mobile theme plus free CDN to speed up the site if you have many images